# Can't access my SSD after accidental formatting

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

My hard drive is not functional after I accidentally formatted it. Every time i try to see partitions using gparted i get the error `end of file while reading /dev/sdb` and both gparted and fdisk both show only 32Kib size on what is a 240GB SSD.

I tried command `sudo hdparm -N /dev/sdb` with result of

```
/dev/sdb:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 00 21 04 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 40 01 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 max sectors   = 64/1(1?), HPA setting seems invalid (buggy kernel device driver?)
```

I want to install Linux after that accident but can't. I can only run live xubuntu with an otherwise unusable computer.

Smartctl says:

```
Short INQUIRY response, skip product id

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK
Current Drive Temperature:     0 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        0 C

Read defect list: asked for grown list but didn't get it
Error Counter logging not supported

Device does not support Self Test logging
```

Comment: Please note the exact brand of the hard driver / ssd? (This might be helpful to some of us.)
You might want to try `smartctl -a /dev/sdb` (and put the relevant output here or on a pastebin) or even `smartctl --xall /dev/sdb`

Comment: i did what u said smartctl with -a gave me just this https://pastebin.com/nwzbzAga

Comment: so then i tried sudo smartctl -a -T permissive /dev/sdb


with output of
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-20-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Short INQUIRY response, skip product id

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK
Current Drive Temperature:     0 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        0 C

Read defect list: asked for grown list but didn't get it
Error Counter logging not supported

Device does not support Self Test logging

Comment: https://pastebin.com/G8xScWp7

Comment: To be honest, this does not look good, at least to me.
Can you please state the exact brand and model. Maybe someone knows something about the model and its particular tricks with SMART.

Comment: What's the output of `lsblk`? (please update your question)

Comment: Could you tell us what exactly you did? How did you format it? Was it mounted? Was it used for the system or as secondary drive? Any RAID setup?

Comment: Note that HPA stands for Host protected area. Basically you can set how large a disk appears to be to a computer (host). If you accidentally set that to 32KB then you now have a 32KB drive (at least until you reset it to a sane value).

Comment: Configuring an HPA usually does not make SMART so uhhh "useless".